# How to Generate nokogumbo Gem File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, nokogiri, sanitize

I recently added the sanitize [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) gem, which appears to have a dependency on the [nokogumbo](https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo) gem, to a site I'm deploying on Heroku. Unfortunately, after installing sanitize, I began receiving the following error on the Heroku deployment:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': /tmp/build_4dbcff4c3c5e0bb6bed481077377225e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.2/ext/nokogiri/nokogiri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogumbo-1.4.12/lib/nokogumboc.so (LoadError)
```

There is no nokogumbo-1.4.12 directory, but everything is working fine locally. I've tried manually installing the gem, but I'm still receiving the same error. Any suggestions for a fix would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue on the nokogumbo gem. https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo/issues/25

> "Downgrading to nokogumbo 1.4.11 fixes Heroku deployment so something is definitely up.
>   The issue appears on both cedar-14 (Ubuntu 14 LTS) and heroku-16 (Ubuntu 16 LTS) stacks."

The suggestion on how to fix this until this issue has been resolved is to downgrade nokogumbo to `1.4.11`.

```
# Fix the version until https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo/issues/25 gets fixed
gem 'nokogumbo', '= 1.4.11'
```